# simple python regular ex not working

Tags: python, regex

Try to regex phone numbers, can't get it to work and don't see what's wrong with my regular expression.
here is the code i'm running:

```
import re

text = 'random text    058-6959503     -'
cellular = re.findall(r'/^05\d([-]{0,1})\d{7}$/',text )
print(cellular)
```

it returns nothing. help?

Comment: use http://regex101.com  or similar sites - try `r'(05\d+-?\d{7})'` if you include groups aka (...) they will dictate whats matched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You regular expression should be

```
r'05\d-?\d{7}'
```

so your full code:

```
import re

text = 'random text    058-6959503     -'
cellular = re.findall(r'05\d-?\d{7}',text )
print(cellular)
```

Output:

> ```
> ['058-6959503']
> ```

Your mistakes/complications:

1. Your phone number is not at the start of the string, so don't use `^`.
2. Your phone number is not at the end of the string, so don't use `$`.
3. Consider using `\b` (word boundary) instead of your original `^` and `$`.
4. Don't use `/` at the start and end of your regular expression.
5. Instead of `{0,1}` you may use `?`.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that the syntax you're using for the regular expression is wrong. You don't need the slashes inside of `r'...'`. Second, even with correct syntax, the regular expression you're using is too strict. `^` indicates you expect the match to start at the beginning of the line and `$` means that it ends with the end of a line. `text` has additional leading and trailing characters, so your regex doesn't match.

You can probably get by with something as simple as `05\d-?\d{7}` for your regex. Note that `-?` does exactly the same thing as `([-]{0,1})`

Answer (score -1):

You can use is digit(), in order to grab the digits

```
text = 'random text    058-6959503     -'
print ''.join(c for c in text if c.isdigit())
0586959503
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like OP will be searching the text for all occurrences of a phone number. This solution seems like it will concatenate all the digits in the source text.